# Trying to understand how to use parseFloat to convert string to number

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers

I'm trying to understand how to user parseFloat to convert a string to a number--which by the way changes based on a users rewards club points.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
var ptsBalance = jQuery('.value.large.withCommas').text(); // get current RC points balance
var strParse = parseInt(ptsBalance, 10); // * Output should be current RC balance
alert(strParse); // alert Rewards Club Balance

var bonusPoints = 70000;
var totalPts = jQuery(strParse + bonusPoints); // sum total of Bonus and Current points

jQuery(strParse).appendTo('.currentPts');
jQuery(totalPts).appendTo('.totalPts'); // insert RC points balance after 'Current Points' text
```

Clearly I'm not using pareFloat, but rather strParse, which is rounding my string. That said, how do I convert a string to a number that could be "10", "100", "1,000", "10,000" etc.?

Here's a link to my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkmills1/60vdfykq/

Still learning...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot currency/number parsing using a library can be beneficial. Something like this [one](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle, change line 4 from:

```
var strParse = parseInt(ptsBalance, 10);
```

to

```
var strParse = parseInt(ptsBalance.replace(',',''), 10);
```

You may also want to remove any other symbols needed, or even use regular expressions to do just that.